# NDSolve fails at the regular singular point of a second-order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, series-expansion, singularity

Here is the ODE I want to numerically integrate,

```
odey=-l (1 + l) R[y] + (k - y) (-2 Derivative[1][R][y] + (k - y) (R^\[Prime]\[Prime])[y])
```

If we rearrange it in the standard form,

$$R''(y)-\frac{2}{k-y}R'(y)-\frac{l(l+1)}{(k-y)^{2}}R(y)=0$$

we see that it has a regular singular point at $y=k$ where $k<0$. I also attempted to solve this using DSolve, and it gave me a solution that conforms with the form I expect, that is $R(y)=c_{1}(y-k)^{a}+c_{2}(y-k)^{b}$

```
DSolve[odey == 0, R[y], y]
```

Now, I want $R(y)$ to vanish for very large $y$ (boundary condition). So I make the transformation $t=1/y$ (where $y=\infty$ corresponds to $t=0$),

```
odet = odey /. R -> (R[1/#] &) /. y -> 1/t // Simplify
```

What I do next is to perform Frobenius method (series solution of $R$)

```
odetSeries = Series[odet /. R -> Function[{t}, t^p Sum[a[i] t^i, {i, 0, 7}]] // Simplify, {t, 0, 4}] // Simplify
```

where the indicial equation to solve is

```
Solve[-(l + l^2 + p - p^2) a[0] == 0, p]
```

I chose $p=1+l$ to satisfy the boundary condition. After which, I obtained the first few coefficients of the expansion $a_{0},a_{1},a_{2}$

```
odetSeries /. p -> 1 + l /. a[1] -> 0 // Simplify
Solve[(k^2 (2 + 3 l + l^2) a[0] + 2 (3 + 2 l) a[2]) == 0, a[2]] //Flatten[#] & // Simplify
odetSeries /. p -> 1 + l /. a[1] -> 0 /. % /. a[3] -> 0 // Simplify
Solve[(-k^4 (24 + 50 l + 35 l^2 + 10 l^3 + l^4) a[0] + 8 (15 + 16 l + 4 l^2) a[4]) == 0, a[4]] // Flatten[#] & // Simplify

a4[l_] := (k^4 (24 + 50 l + 35 l^2 + 10 l^3 + l^4) a0)/(8 (15 + 16 l + 4 l^2));
a2[l_] := -((k^2 (2 + 3 l + l^2) a0)/(6 + 4 l));

solInfPlus[l_] := t^(1 + l) (a0 + a2[l] t^2 + a4[l] t^4);
testsol = solInfPlus[l] /. t -> 1/y
Collect[testsol, y, Simplify] /. a0 -> 1
D[testsol, y] /. a0 -> 1 // Collect[#, y, Simplify] &

R[y_, l_] := (1/y)^(1 + l) - (k^2 (2 + 3 l + l^2) (1/y)^(3 + l))/(6 + 4 l) + (k^4 (24 + 50 l + 35 l^2 + 10 l^3 + l^4) (1/y)^(5 + l))/(8 (15 + 16 l + 4 l^2))
dR[y_, l_] := -(1 + l) (1/y)^(2 + l) + (k^2 (6 + 11 l + 6 l^2 + l^3) (1/y)^(4 + l))/(6 + 4 l) - (k^4 (120 + 274 l + 225 l^2 + 85 l^3 + 15 l^4 + l^5) (1/y)^(6 + l))/(8 (15 + 16 l + 4 l^2))
```

Now, I execute numerical calculations.

```
k=(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[-(1/3)])/(3 Gamma[1/6]);

rules = {AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxSteps -> 10000};
rat = 10^-30;
yP = 10^3;
yM = -10^3;
y0 = 10^-2; 

For[el = 0, el <= 8, el++, {
 R0p = Rationalize[R[yP, el], rat];
 dR0p = Rationalize[dR[yP, el], rat];
 R0m = Rationalize[R[yM, el], rat];
 dR0m = Rationalize[dR[yM, el], rat];

 Rsolp = R /. First@NDSolve[{(odey /. l -> el) == 0, R[yP] == R0p, R'[yP] == dR0p}, {R}, {y, yP, y0}, rules];
 Rsolm = R /. First@NDSolve[{(odey /. l -> el) == 0, R[yM] == R0m, R'[yM] == dR0m}, {R}, {y, yM, y0}, rules];

rp = Rationalize[ Rsolp[y0], rat];
rm = Rationalize[ Rsolm[y0], rat];
drp = Rationalize[ Rsolp'[y0], rat];
drm = Rationalize[ Rsolm'[y0], rat];

s = Rationalize[(-Q a Sqrt[4 Pi (2 el + 1)])/(a(y0-k))^2,rat];
c1f = (rm s)/(drp rm - drm rp);(*jump condition at y=y0 between Rsolp and Rsolm*)
baremode[el] = Sqrt[(2 el + 1)/(4 \[Pi])] (c1f Rsolp'[y0]);}]
```

But the solver stops evaluating exactly at $y=k=-0.431188993916544683366628968310$, this is the regular singular point of the ODE above. Specifically, the NDSolve fails in Rsolm since Rsolm covers the region from $yM=-10^{3}$ to $y0=10^{-2}$ in which the singularity $y=k=-0.431188993916544683366628968310$ belongs.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I am thinking of integrating near the singular point, bypass it and then continue integrating. But I do not have an idea on how to execute it properly.

Comment: What equation do you want to solve - `odey` or ` in the standard form`? At first glance, these are different equations. Or did you make a mistake?

Comment: Hi @AlexTrounev, they are just the same. But you can just consider odey since it's a homogeneous ODE

Comment: Watch carefully compare degrees $(k-y)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see the brackets.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I am thinking of a sort of numerical continuation methods. I guess it will help? Or, a good coordinate transformation so that the ode is free from singular points. I don't know exactly. I hope you can help me with this

Comment: I'm struggeling: Mathematica can solve  your ode  `DSolve[odey == 0, R[y], y]` . After simplification the result is `R[y]=c1(k-y)^l+c2/(k-y)^(1+l)` . What is your purpose for the further calculations?

Comment: Hi, @UlrichNeumann, in my case, it is impossible for me to find the constants $c_{1}, c_{2}$ since my problem does not deal with initial conditions. The only necessary boundary condition is that $R$ vanishes for very large $y$. So the only way is to integrate odey over the domain I am interested. That's why I used NDSolve, and it so happens that the regular singular point is within the domain of integration. Thus, NDSolve fails.

Comment: What do you know about parameter `l`?

Comment: $l=0,1,2,3,...$

Comment: Isn't $c_1$ arbitrary for $a= -1-l<0$ and $c_2=0$ for $b=l>0$ in the `DSolve[odey == 0, R, y]` solution?

Answer (score 2):

We write the equation in the form

```
odey = -l (1 + l) R[y] - 2*(k - y)*R'[y] + (k - y)^2*R''[y]
```

Make a replacement coefficient at the second derivative $(k-y)^2\to(k-y)^2+h^2$:

```
 odey = -l (1 + l) R[y] - 2*(k - y)*R'[y] + ((k - y)^2+h^2)*R''[y]
```

Choose `h` of the order of the minimum integration step.

Example

```
odey = -l (1 + l) R1[y] - 
    2*(k - y)*R1'[y] + ((k - y)^2 + h^2)*R1''[y] == 0;


k = (Sqrt[π] Gamma[-(1/3)])/(3 Gamma[1/6]); h = 10^-5;
R[y_, l_] := (1/y)^(1 + l) - (k^2 (2 + 3 l + l^2) (1/y)^(3 + l))/(6 + 
     4 l) + (k^4 (24 + 50 l + 35 l^2 + 10 l^3 + 
       l^4) (1/y)^(5 + l))/(8 (15 + 16 l + 4 l^2))
dR[y_, l_] := -(1 + l) (1/y)^(2 + 
      l) + (k^2 (6 + 11 l + 6 l^2 + l^3) (1/y)^(4 + l))/(6 + 
     4 l) - (k^4 (120 + 274 l + 225 l^2 + 85 l^3 + 15 l^4 + 
       l^5) (1/y)^(6 + l))/(8 (15 + 16 l + 4 l^2))
yP = 10^3;
yM = -10^3;
y0 = 10^-2;
a = 1; Q = 1; l = 4; el = l;
R0p = R[yP, el];
dR0p = dR[yP, el];
R0m = R[yM, el];
dR0m = dR[yM, el];



s1 = NDSolve[{odey, R1[yP] == R0p, R1'[yP] == dR0p}, R1, {y, y0, yP}]

s2 = NDSolve[{odey, R1[yM] == R0m, R1'[yM] == dR0m}, R1, {y, yM, y0}]

{Plot[R1[y] /. s1, {y, y0, yP}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"l=", l}]], 
 Plot[R1[y] /. s2, {y, yM, y0}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]

An example of using an exact solution

```
rl[ρ_, b0_, 
  q_] := ρ (1 - (Sqrt[π] Gamma[1/(q - 1)])/((1 - q) Gamma[
         1/2 ((q + 1)/(q - 1))]) b0/ρ)
r1[ρ_] := rl[ρ, a1, -2];
f0 = 1 - a1^3/r1[a1 y0]^3;
R[y_, l_] := (1/y)^(1 + 
      l) - ((2 + 3 l + l^2) π (1/y)^(3 + l) Gamma[2/3]^2)/(2 (3 + 
        2 l) Gamma[1/6]^2) + ((24 + 50 l + 35 l^2 + 10 l^3 + 
        l^4) π^2 (1/y)^(5 + l) Gamma[2/3]^4)/(8 (15 + 16 l + 
        4 l^2) Gamma[1/6]^4);
dR[y_, l_] := -(1 + l) (1/y)^(2 + 
       l) + ((6 + 11 l + 6 l^2 + l^3) π (1/y)^(4 + l) Gamma[
        2/3]^2)/(2 (3 + 2 l) Gamma[1/6]^2) - ((120 + 274 l + 
        225 l^2 + 85 l^3 + 15 l^4 + l^5) π^2 (1/y)^(6 + l) Gamma[
        2/3]^4)/(8 (15 + 16 l + 4 l^2) Gamma[1/6]^4);
y0 = 10^-3;
yP = 10^3;
yM = -10^3;
a1 = 1;
b = a1 Sqrt[π] Gamma[2/3]/Gamma[1/6];
a = (a1 Sqrt[π] Gamma[2/3])/Gamma[1/6];
Q = 1;
R0p = R[yP, el];
dR0p = dR[yP, el];
R0m = R[yM, el];
dR0m = dR[yM, el];
sol = DSolve[-l (1 + l) R1[ρ] + 
     2 (ρ + b) R1'[ρ] + (ρ + a)^2*R1''[ρ] == 0, 
   R1, ρ];
Rs = First[ R1[ρ] /. sol] /. ρ -> y;
eq1 = Rs /. {y -> yP};
eq2 = D[Rs, y] /. {y -> yP};
sC1 = Solve[eq1 == R0p && eq2 == dR0p, {C[1], C[2]}];
Rs1 = Rs /. sC1;
eq3 = Rs /. {y -> yM};
eq4 = D[Rs, y] /. {y -> yM};
sC2 = Solve[eq3 == R0m && eq2 == dR0m, {C[1], C[2]}];
Rs2 = Rs /. sC2;
Rsolp = Rs1 /. l -> el;
Rsolm = Rs2 /. l -> el;
rp = Rsolp /. y -> y0;
rm = Rsolm /. y -> y0;
drp = D[Rsolp, y] /. y -> y0;
drm = D[Rsolm, y] /. y -> y0;
s = (-Q a1 Sqrt[4 Pi (2 el + 1)])/(rl[a1 y0, a1, -2])^2;
c1f = (rm s)/(drp rm - drm rp); baremode = 
 Sqrt[(2 el + 1)/(4 π)] (c1f D[Rsolp, y] /. y -> y0);

Table[{Plot[Rsolp /. el -> i, {y, y0, yP}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"l=", i}]], 
  Plot[Rsolm /. el -> i, {y, y0, yM}]}, {i, 1, 4}]
```

[image: fig2]

The case $l=0$ is degenerate, therefore the exact solution is determined differently. To combine the two cases, divide the code into two blocks, and then combine them using `If[]`:

```
rl[\[Rho]_, b0_, 
  q_] := \[Rho] (1 - (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/(q - 1)])/((1 - q) Gamma[
         1/2 ((q + 1)/(q - 1))]) b0/\[Rho])
r1[\[Rho]_] := rl[\[Rho], a1, -2];
f0 = 1 - a1^3/r1[a1 y0]^3;
R[y_, l_] := (1/y)^(1 + 
      l) - ((2 + 3 l + l^2) \[Pi] (1/y)^(3 + l) Gamma[2/3]^2)/(2 (3 + 
        2 l) Gamma[1/6]^2) + ((24 + 50 l + 35 l^2 + 10 l^3 + 
        l^4) \[Pi]^2 (1/y)^(5 + l) Gamma[2/3]^4)/(8 (15 + 16 l + 
        4 l^2) Gamma[1/6]^4);
dR[y_, l_] := -(1 + l) (1/y)^(2 + 
       l) + ((6 + 11 l + 6 l^2 + l^3) \[Pi] (1/y)^(4 + l) Gamma[
        2/3]^2)/(2 (3 + 2 l) Gamma[1/6]^2) - ((120 + 274 l + 
        225 l^2 + 85 l^3 + 15 l^4 + l^5) \[Pi]^2 (1/y)^(6 + l) Gamma[
        2/3]^4)/(8 (15 + 16 l + 4 l^2) Gamma[1/6]^4);
y0 = 10^-3;
yP = 10^3;
yM = -10^3;
a1 = 1;
b = a1 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[2/3]/Gamma[1/6];
a = (a1 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[2/3])/Gamma[1/6];
Q = 1;
Baremode[L_] := Block[{el = L}, R0p = R[yP, el];
   dR0p = dR[yP, el];
   R0m = R[yM, el];
   dR0m = dR[yM, el];
   sol = DSolve[-l (1 + l) R1[\[Rho]] + 
       2 (\[Rho] + b) R1'[\[Rho]] + (\[Rho] + a)^2*R1''[\[Rho]] == 0, 
     R1, \[Rho]];
   Rs = First[ R1[\[Rho]] /. sol] /. \[Rho] -> y;
   eq1 = Rs /. {y -> yP};
   eq2 = D[Rs, y] /. {y -> yP};
   sC1 = Solve[eq1 == R0p && eq2 == dR0p, {C[1], C[2]}];
   Rs1 = Rs /. sC1;
   eq3 = Rs /. {y -> yM};
   eq4 = D[Rs, y] /. {y -> yM};
   sC2 = Solve[eq3 == R0m && eq2 == dR0m, {C[1], C[2]}];
   Rs2 = Rs /. sC2;
   Rsolp = Rs1 /. l -> el;
   Rsolm = Rs2 /. l -> el;
   rp = Rsolp /. y -> y0;
   rm = Rsolm /. y -> y0;
   drp = D[Rsolp, y] /. y -> y0;
   drm = D[Rsolm, y] /. y -> y0;
   s = (-Q a1 Sqrt[4 Pi (2 el + 1)])/(rl[a1 y0, a1, -2])^2;
   c1f = (rm s)/(drp rm - drm rp); 
   baremode = Sqrt[(2 el + 1)/(4 \[Pi])] (c1f D[Rsolp, y] /. y -> y0);
    Re[baremode]];
Baremode0[L0_] := Block[{el = L0},
   R0p = R[yP, el];
   dR0p = dR[yP, el];
   R0m = R[yM, el];
   dR0m = dR[yM, el];
   sol = DSolve[
     2 (\[Rho] + b) R1'[\[Rho]] + (\[Rho] + a)^2*R1''[\[Rho]] == 0, 
     R1, \[Rho]];
   Rs = First[ R1[\[Rho]] /. sol] /. \[Rho] -> y;
   eq1 = Rs /. {y -> yP};
   eq2 = D[Rs, y] /. {y -> yP};
   sC1 = Solve[eq1 == R0p && eq2 == dR0p, {C[1], C[2]}];
   Rsolp = Rs /. sC1;
   eq3 = Rs /. {y -> yM};
   eq4 = D[Rs, y] /. {y -> yM};
   sC2 = Solve[eq3 == R0m && eq2 == dR0m, {C[1], C[2]}];
   Rsolm = Rs /. sC2;
   rp = Rsolp /. y -> y0;
   rm = Rsolm /. y -> y0;
   drp = D[Rsolp, y] /. y -> y0;
   drm = D[Rsolm, y] /. y -> y0;
   s = (-Q a1 Sqrt[4 Pi ])/(rl[a1 y0, a1, -2])^2;
   c1f = (rm s)/(drp rm - drm rp); 
   baremode = Sqrt[1/(4 \[Pi])] (c1f D[Rsolp, y] /. y -> y0); 
   Re[baremode]];
```

Use the code with `If[]` for printing `baremode` (we dropped the zero imaginary part):

```
For[k = 0, k <= 4, k++, 
 Print[{Row[{"l=", k}], 
   Row[{"baremode=", 
     First[If[k == 0, N[Baremode0[0], 6], N[Baremode[k], 6]]]}]}]]
{l=0,baremode=-7.18650*10^6}

{l=1,baremode=-9.94531*10^10}

{l=2,baremode=-1.14027*10^20}

{l=3,baremode=-6.65090*10^24}

{l=4,baremode=-2.09589*10^33}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'of the order of the minimum integration step'? And what does the replacement coefficient do?

Comment: Put `h=10^-5;`, it is enough to get through `y=k`.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it. I will let you know what it will end up. Thanks @Alex

Comment: NDSolve still fails NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point y == -0.431183866743419284299032955175.

Comment: There is another problem. You try to calculate large  numbers of order `Exp[10^3]`

Comment: What quantity are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, your code does not work  on version 11.3, so many errors occur. I debugged the code, see the update.

Comment: I will try the debugged version. But @Alex, can you please check on the way how I carried out the series solution of $R$, specifically in obtaining the coefficients of the expansion (e.i. I set odd coefficients $a_{1},a_{3}$, set $a_{0}=1$ and solved for $a_{2},a_{4}$. Was that ok?

Comment: There is an exact solution. What are the series solution or numerical solution for?

Comment: Hi @Alex, I tried your new code and it blows up for $l=0$.

Comment: Hi @Alex, what I need is to compute numerically the baremode in the for loop, for every mode $el=0,1,2,3,4,...$. Can I ask you to modify your code into for loop. Thank you

Comment: @user583893 See update.

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for the update.Regarding the your first answer, how can we justify the addition of coefficient in the second derivative of the ODE? What does it actually do in bypassing the singular point at $y=k$?

Comment: @user583893 Sorry, did not see your question. There is no division by 0 at `y=k` with $h^2>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your ode is (l >= 0):

```
odey /. R -> Function[y, (c1 (k - y)^l + c2/(k - y)^(1 + l)) ]
(* 0 *)
```

The special solution `Limit[R[y],y->Infinity]==0` requires `c1->0`:

```
 R~1/(k - y)^(1 + l)
```

Comment: Right, so what we do with $y=k$? It blows up

Comment: Yes, and the asymptotic solution shows you how the singularity is "passed".

Comment: I don't quite understand what you really mean

Comment: The solution of odey shows a part vanishing for y->infinity (c1=0,c2!=0) and a part without singularity (c2==0,c1!=0) but increasing with y! That means the only solution without singularity, vanishing with y-> infinity is `R==0`

Comment: I get that. But how do I actually evaluate $R$ at $y=k$? I just use $R\sim(k-y)^{l}$?

Comment: @user583893 $R$ is singular at $y=k$, you can't evaluate it there. The other solution doesn't satisfy your boundary condition at $y\to\infty$, so you can't use it either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you simply want to skip past the singularity in a numerical solver, you can deform your integration path by walking around the singularity in the complex plane. This will work for $l\in\mathbb N_0$ since the singularity will be a pole, so the continuation is unique. Try e.g. parametrizing your $y$ as

$$y(t)=\begin{cases}t+i\cos\left(\frac\pi{2\epsilon}(k-t)\right)^3 & \text{if } k-\epsilon\le t\le k+\epsilon, \\
t & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Then express $R'(y)$ and $R''(y)$ in terms of another function $g(t)=R(y(t))$ and use `NDSolve` to find $g$. After this you can get $R(y)$ back (in our parametrization it's trivial for $y\not\in(k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon)$).

Example:

```
y[t_] = Piecewise[{{t + I*Cos[(Pi/(2*ϵ))*(k - t)]^3, k - ϵ <= t <= k + ϵ}, {t, True}}];
yp[t_] = y'[t] // Simplify;
ypp[t_] = y''[t] // Simplify;

k = (Sqrt[π] Gamma[-(1/3)])/(3 Gamma[1/6]);
l = 3;
ϵ = 0.1;

sol[t_] = NDSolveValue[{1/yp[t]^2 (g''[t] - ypp[t]/yp[t] g'[t]) -
                        2/(k - y[t])g'[t]/yp[t]-(l(l+1))/(k - y[t])^2 g[t] == 0,
                        g[10] == 0, g'[10] == -1}, g[t], {t, -1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];

(* Make sure that the solution is proportional to exact solution *)
Plot[sol[t]/(k - y[t])^(-1 - l), {t, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

> [image: output from Plot]

Comment: Hi @Ruslan, how can I actually retrieve $R(y)$ from the result of NDSolve for $g(t)$?

Comment: @user583893 by construction of `y[t]`, $R(y)=g(y)=g(t)\;\forall y\not\in(k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon)$. Just make sure $\epsilon$ is small enough that you don't care about the excluded interval.

Comment: Can you update your answer including the actual code retrieving $R(y)$ @Ruslan? Thank you

Comment: @user583893 it's trivial: `R[Y_]=Piecewise[{{Indeterminate, k-ϵ<=Y<=k+ϵ}, {sol[Y], True}}]`

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what is the motivation for the form of the parametrization?

Comment: @user583893 I wanted it to be smooth, i.e. have first and second derivatives continuous, so that the ODE didn't break down due to the discontinuities in the first derivative, and so as to help the solver have decent precision (due to avoidance of cusps in the functions). Piecewise definition is to make $t=y$ outside the "walk-around" part.

Comment: It's kind of a window function right?

Comment: @user583893 no, it's unrelated to window functions – it's simply a smooth(ish) curve. See it visualized with `ParametricPlot3D[{t, Re@#, Im@#} &@y[t], {t, -1, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "Re", "Im"}, PlotRange -> All]`. You can use any other function satisfying the smoothness requirements.

Comment: I think I can also use the hyperbolic tangent, as long as it satisfies the smoothness properties right?

Comment: @user583893 I don't quite understand how you'd use $\tanh$ to walk around the singularity. $\tanh$ maps reals to reals, while $y(t)$ here steps away from the real line for $t\in(k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Hi @Ruslan, in my case I have initial conditions in which my $t$ is negative. As a consequence $g(t)$ becomes a complex number, and it is unphysical (in the problem that I am working) to have complex-valued solution of the ODE. The complex-valuedness of the solution arises from your construction of $y(t)$ (the smooth function). How do I possibly fix it? Thanks again

Comment: @user583893 choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that your initial condition point is not moved away from the real line.

Comment: I used $\epsilon=10^{-5}$. So I guess, the order of magnitude is not yet enough. Ok, I'll try another. Thanks @Ruslan. I'll update you

Comment: @user583893 you may be having problems with precision of `NDSolve`. Try using various options described in the documentation to increase precision.

Comment: Also, the NDSolve fails at $l>8$. I don't know why.

Comment: @user583893 this is a topic for another question. This conversation has already grown longer than it should have (notice the warnings appearing when you try to enter a comment).

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan. I'll just make another topic post, I guess.